# Trigger a function after receiving welcome message

Tags: javascript, botframework, bots

I have a bot web client. In which i am triggering welcome message with below code.

```
directLine.postActivity({
from: { id: 'myUserId', name: 'myUserName' },
type: 'message',
 }).subscribe(
id => console.log("Posted activity, assigned ID ", id),
error => console.log("Error posting activity", error)
 );
```

Below welcome message I want to have Most popular items. for that under .Subscribe i am calling a function like below.

```
.subscribe( BotPostRender(););
```

It is rendering the most popular items before receiving welcome message, Is there any way to call the function after receiving welcome message?

```
function BotPostRender() {
$(".wc-message-group-content").append('<div class=feeds-wrapper><div class=chat-feeds><h5>Most Popular</h5><ul class=chat-feed-lists><li><a class=mp-options href=javascript:;>People</a><li><a class=mp-options href=javascript:;>Food Menu</a></ul></div></div>');
$(".mp-options").click(function (){GetResult($(this).text());});}
```

Comment: Unless BotPostRender returns a function, it looks like you have your subscribe handler misconstructed . `subscribe` takes a function - not a function call. Try `.subscribe( BotPostRender);`, and take a look at the [rsjx documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription) on subscriptions.

Comment: Have tried this. Same behaviour :(

Comment: Have you tried adding an error handler as well? `.subscribe(BotPostRender, error => console.log(error));`. If it's throwing an error, that might help you debug it.

Comment: Yes I have tried this. Actually there is no error. I am getting welcome message from bot, But before receiving welcome message this most popular code gets executed, so it is showing both the results in wrong order.

Comment: Can you add the `BotPostRender` method to your question?

Comment: i have added the function in Question

Comment: Are you using Web Chat v3 - it is deprecated and no longer supported. I would recommend update to [v4](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples). I would also look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tdurnford/e01b0bd6431ad9ae6d801f90235fa1d2) for more details regarding welcome messages in Web Chat. In the meantime -  I will continue to look into your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BotChat.Js file performWork is the function which will get executed whenever we send or receive messages from bot.

In this i have written code to call my function after receiving welcome message.

```
if (rendercount == 2)
{ // rendercount - i am incrementing whenever we send/receive message
  rendercount = 3;
  BotPostRender(); // calling my function after receiving welcome message.
 }
```